# Android screen recorder will let camera preview go black one second when recorder starting

Tags: android, camera, android-mediarecorder

I found that when video recorder is start, the camera preview will go black one screen(Only camera preview)

I've developed Camera view to display on screen, when some condition full-fill, i will start screen recorder.

```
mMediaProjectionManager = getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager;
```

Comment: Screen recording may not save camera preview surface on some devices. If you only care about camera, use Media reorder instead.